# Where'd my 'Similar Questions' title go?

Tags: bug, status-completed

When I logged into SuperUser today, I noticed that I had a new badge. Rather than Xing it out, I just let it be. And so it stayed there when I went to ask a question.

But before I asked my question, I noticed an odd bug: I could no longer see the title of the yellow sidebar that said 'Similar Questions'.

So here is a screenshot of the bug:
[image: A screenshot of me asking a question on SuperUser in Chrome with AdBlock installed.]
And here is one with [freehand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775): :)
[image: A screenshot of me asking a question on SuperUser in Chrome with AdBlock installed. WITH FREEHAND CIRCLES!]

Obviously, this is me using SuperUser on the latest Chrome [12.0.742.112] on Windows 7.

Answer (score 11):

solution: click the [x] on the notification bar. :)

Comment: But Jeff we want you to spend countless hours sifting through code and find a way to fix this simple issue ;P

Comment: Best part is, the fix could simply be 10 characters in the style sheet.